# How to join KStream and GlobalKTable with null keys and join values in json payload?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a `KStream` with `null` key and value json as follows:

```
{"booking_id":12,....}
```

And a `GlobalKTable` which also has `null` key and the booking id in its JSON payload.

I want to perform a join using `booking_id` field as key.

I am aware of `KeyValueMapper` for `KStream` but since both of these keys are `null` how can I perform join operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a GlobalKTable it **must** have the key properly set to be used for the join.

If your original topic does have a `null` key, you would need to extract the key from JSON and write the result back into a second topic. Afterwards, you can read the second topic back as a `GlobalKTable` to be used for the join.